# Cannot call database script document in Notes. Cannot find external name error

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In a database I have a database script code which only contains this code:

```vb
Use "uiMaatwerk"

Sub Querydocumentdelete(Source As Notesuidatabase, Continue As Variant)

    If Not DeleteDocument(Source.Documents, False) Then
        Continue = False 
    End If

End Sub
```

The `DeleteDocument()` is a function which is in another scriptLibrary called `uiMaatwerk3`. `uiMaatwerk` has `Use uiMaatwerk2` and `uiMaatwerk2` has `uiMaatwerk3`

But whenever I select a document in the Notes client and then press the delete button then I see this warning:

[image]

I tried deleting all the scriptlibraries and the database scriptlibrary and then created new scriptlibraries and recopied the code. But it's still not working. I cannot use recompile or build whole database because then database will not work again..

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this construct: the database script will only be reloaded, when the database is closed completely: close all open windows of it in Client AND close the database in designer as well (use right click  close command from database).

After that all code will be reloaded and your „use“ will work.